# Python fuctional style iterative algoritm?

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, iteration

In Haskell there is a simple list function available

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x =  x : iterate f (f x)
```

In python it could be implemented as following:

```
def iterate(f, init):
  while True:
    yield init
    init = f(init)
```

I was kinda surprised that something basic like this is not part of the functools/itertools modules. Could it be simply costructed in functional style (i.e. without the loop) using the tools provided in these libraries? (Mostly code golf, trying to learn about functional style in Python.)

Comment: There are quite a few useful things left out of the standard library `itertools` modules. Take a look at https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/ and https://pypi.org/project/toolz/ for most of the missing pieces.

Comment: When I'm doing functional programming in Python and I find I'm missing a basic combinator I would have used in a more functional language, I just write the utility in the most natural/efficient way I can think of. Which frequently means with imperative loops inside. I only care about being able to *use* it to support code elsewhere where I'm already thinking in functional style, there's no virtue in being "functional all the way down". (Python generators are fundamentally impure anyway, so there's no escaping thinking imperatively while doing "functional" composition of itertools operations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using some of the functions in `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import accumulate, repeat

def iterate(func, initial):
    return accumulate(repeat(None), func=lambda tot, _: func(tot), initial=initial)
```

Although it's clearly not very clean. Itertools is missing some fundamental functions for constructing streams, like `unfoldr`. Most of the `itertools` functions could be defined in terms of `unfoldr`, as it happens, but functional programming is a little uncomfortable in Python anyways so that might not be much of a benefit.

Comment: Thanks, I think you managed to put precise wording to my vague idea! I agree that lack of an unfolding function is the core problem. Consuming the dummy `repeat(None)` is kind of awkward, but I guess this workaround is as good as it can get.

Answer (score 5):

There is a 3rd-party "extension" to the `itertools` module, `more-iterools`,  that includes (among many other things) an [`iterate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#iterate) function defined exactly like you observed:

```
# Exact definition, minus the doc string...
def iterate(func, start):
    while True:
        yield start
        start = func(start)
```

Python lacks the optimization necessary to make a recursive definition like

```
def iterate(func, start):
    yield from chain([start], iterate(func, func(start))
```

feasible.

---

If you are curious, [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org) is a superset of Python that *does* do things like tail-call optimization. Try the following code at https://cs121-team-panda.github.io/coconut-interpreter/:

```
@recursive_iterator
def iterate(f, s) = (s,) :: iterate(f, f(s))

for x in iterate(x -> x + 1, 0)$[1000:1010]:
    print(x)
```

(I'm not entirely sure the `recursive_iterator` decorator is necessary. The iteration slice demonstrates, I think, that this avoids the recursion-depth error similar code in Python would produce.)

Comment: The coconut solution looks interesting but also very slow. Getting the value at index `i` with `next(iterate(x -> x + 1, 0)$[i:i+1])` takes me 0.1 seconds for i=1000 and 0.4 seconds for i=2000. The slowness and the four times longer time when doubling the index suggest that it takes O(i^2) time. [Results and code](https://pastebin.com/raw/e1d4xrzR).

Comment: Very surprisingly, it also seems to take O(i^2) *memory*. For i=1000, 2000, and 4000, tracemalloc reports 6, 21 and 80 MB. The "Python" checkbox in the top right apparently toggles to showing the generated Python code, which helps a bit, but doesn't show the whole picture. Anyway, can you tell whether quadratic time/space are correct, and whether that's because of coconut itself or because of the way you're using it (i.e., can it be improved to linear time/space by using it better)?

Comment: I'm not sure about either. Coconut works (AFAIK) by transforming the source code itself into valid Python, which then gets executed by the ordinary Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [walrus operator<sup>*</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) in a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to get desired output.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def f(x):
    return x + 10

x = 0
it = chain([x], (x:=f(x) for _ in repeat(None)))
```

---

```
>>> next(it)
0
>>> next(it)
10
>>> next(it)
20
```

---

<sub>* [Walrus operator is available from python3.8 or above](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)</sub>

Comment: Interesting idea. Using `x` as a stateful variable doesn't feel very functional style, but this is still a neat trick, thanks!

Comment: Not very functional though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can construct it "loop-less" with `map` and `itertools`, and it's faster than the others:

```
from itertools import tee, chain, islice

def iterate(f, init):
    parts = [[init]]
    values1, values2 = tee(chain.from_iterable(parts))
    parts.append(map(f, values2))
    return values1

def f(x):
    return 3 * x

print(*islice(iterate(f, 1), 10))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/RCsMgDEXf/Yo8aillXV/GYF8yynBtpEKrounovt5Z69gCgXCTnNy4N03WdBfnY1TeLqAJPVk7B9CLs56AEGsYJqlNDTrMekDGRlR5UBJylWSjSVwZpHDSU4Ab3O@72PdZfMl5xdDWpTinfqLyDG32q48Me87I874QP1YjnUMz8kW6/VQhlAmPtHrz5R@@FN@Kl9LtoIKNMee1IV4dL/A/961IeRIixg8)):

```
1 3 9 27 81 243 729 2187 6561 19683
```

The first problem is that we need the values both for the outside user and fed back into itself to compute further values. We can use `tee` to duplicate the values.

Next we have a chicken-and-egg problem: We want to use `map(f, values2)` to get the function values, where `values2` comes from the `map` iterator that we're only about to create! Fortunately, `chain.from_iterable` takes an iterable that we can extend *after* creating the `chain`.

Alternatively, we can make `parts` a generator, as that accesses `values2` only after it's created:

```
def iterate(f, init):
    def parts():
        yield init,
        yield map(f, values2)
    values1, values2 = tee(chain.from_iterable(parts()))
    return values1
```

Benchmark for computing 100,000 values with `f = abs` and `init = 0` (just something fast to minimize the dilution of the speed differences of the solutions):

```
CPython 3.8.0b4 on tio.run:

    mean  stdev  (from best 5 of 20 attempts)
 2.75 ms  0.03 ms  with_itertools1  (my first solution)
 2.76 ms  0.02 ms  with_itertools2  (my second solution)
 5.29 ms  0.02 ms  with_generator   (the question's solution)
 5.73 ms  0.04 ms  with_walrus
 9.00 ms  0.09 ms  with_accumulate

CPython 3.10.4 on my Windows laptop:

    mean  stdev  (from best 5 of 20 attempts)
 8.37 ms  0.02 ms  with_itertools2
 8.37 ms  0.00 ms  with_itertools1
17.86 ms  0.00 ms  with_generator
20.73 ms  0.01 ms  with_walrus
26.03 ms  0.24 ms  with_accumulate

CPython 3.10.4 on a Debian Google Compute Engine instance:

    mean  stdev  (from best 5 of 20 attempts)
 2.25 ms  0.00 ms  with_itertools1
 2.26 ms  0.00 ms  with_itertools2
 3.91 ms  0.00 ms  with_generator
 4.43 ms  0.00 ms  with_walrus
 7.14 ms  0.01 ms  with_accumulate
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTbitswEH33V8xLiRyE2WRZKIb8Qp/6FoJRnPFG1JKNJO8mLPvt6ehix3WzFOoH2xqNzjlz0fRXd@708/fe3G6N6RRIh8Z1XWtBqr4zDkRdD2pohUMODulVn4XUHKRtZU1Lgz0KlyVvJxVKlwWoo7RYuxFHakufuGOEPnmuuGPPQ9O0GLesE05aJ@tJgEJBdNad8G1ksVebZSds4F26c3VXyBrSpaXLywzoMegGo2cRsCiW/eg05hyaQde7VqjjSYDrHIeqhIbRXx5hpGh3AW5G9ooajXCdWXC9n2WL8NMMGNf@uUpsT8FpMvkF7IhlifsuWjPYxwGEjLP9pQxqDhwY/TbskkPTGajoBMwDy@e4Uz03C@xeGGdJyn4fQA/B@CbaAe2Gp58t7VPNWRBQ@PoEPHFskYXzRDVhFaLvUZ@YEr2nSgjJI0WS8B/p2y70eY@Ay/JHGeUL24L1v6Jh@RdqbdcOTnY65CuW@8/G43fj1CAzWyzuzHCvyiPjlmeHLPO1HYl9iScRMR1BOtGQpHGHpV6@lPAMa7hw2KT6GKkdW8cry8aTtP1EnT6eLqpKC4VVldqnJqpBzd11qoTGi2N/gWnvwCG0YJYJ51D1znI4ovUtv33i8JL5@eCz@DGylrA/wJehfmb3Dhf6FdkIm5Sk0cGmAzHef6TOP14I6VB0seLMKtIVijksp/Cn5IojBeMTtnlar1/oqwd1RLPbpKaJ19sPuYBo9@NJurDekGexDM3Ke/qpBnGqAbA4L32iPvz7E7oGPsZYP2GKepU/aAvj8HTPAIdfeN0FBcUrjrcpXPWFrH3puQ6zDll9eym2DSgLK@qfLXwD5nUyYqb1Bp/THL4bvuifCDdGTOO6oMndokLtxzv5ek/u53jxhsaSJb/dfgM)):

```
from itertools import accumulate, tee, chain, islice, repeat
import timeit
from bisect import insort
from random import shuffle
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys

def with_accumulate(f, init):
    return accumulate(repeat(None), func=lambda tot, _: f(tot), initial=init)

def with_generator(f, init):
    while True:
        yield init
        init = f(init)

def with_walrus(f, init):
    return chain([x:=init], (x:=f(x) for _ in repeat(None)))

def with_itertools1(f, init):
    parts = [[init]]
    values1, values2 = tee(chain.from_iterable(parts))
    parts.append(map(f, values2))
    return values1

def with_itertools2(f, init):
    def parts():
        yield init,
        yield map(f, values2)
    values1, values2 = tee(chain.from_iterable(parts()))
    return values1

solutions = [
    with_accumulate,
    with_generator,
    with_walrus,
    with_itertools1,
    with_itertools2,
]

for solution in solutions:
    iterator = solution(lambda x: 3 * x, 1)
    print(*islice(iterator, 10), solution.__name__)

def consume(iterator, n):
    next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)

attempts, best = 20, 5
times = {solution: [] for solution in solutions}
for _ in range(attempts):
    shuffle(solutions)
    for solution in solutions:
        time = min(timeit.repeat(lambda: consume(solution(abs, 0), 10**5), number=1))
        insort(times[solution], time)
print(f'    mean  stdev  (from best {best} of {attempts} attempts)')
for solution in sorted(solutions, key=times.get):
    ts = times[solution][:best]
    print('%5.2f ms ' * 2 % (mean(ts) * 1e3, stdev(ts) * 1e3), solution.__name__)

print()
print(sys.implementation.name, sys.version)
```